# Implement show more and show less in react hooks page throws error of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

While trying to implement `Show More and Show less` in my React hooks page, I am getting Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading substring). Could someone please advise what could be the issue ?
The above error occurred in the  component:

```
at MiddleSection (http://localhost:3000/main.2efdffa93468c998df75.hot-update.js:92:82)
at div
at Home
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41795:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41728:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40537:5)
at App
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18525
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18558
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13092
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
at MiddleSection (middleSection.js:56:1)

```
// textData1.js
        import React from 'react';
    
        const TextData ="We are an awesome bunch of friendly people. We play together for fun and enjoy every moments of soccer.";
        export default TextData 

//middleSection.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import data1 from "../data/textData1";
    const MiddleSection = () => {
         const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);
         const { text } = TextData;
    
        return (
                   <div className='row'>
                        <div className="middleTextContent">
                            <p id="middleTextOverlay">
                                {showMore ? text : `${text.substring(0, 50)} `}
                                 <button className='showMoreLess' onClick={ () => 
                                    setShowMore(!showMore)}>
                                    {showMore ? "Show less": "Show More"}
                                 </button>
                            </p> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
     )
    }
    export default MiddleSection;
```

Comment: Why you are trying to destructure a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TextData` is a string, so when you destructure it with `const { text } = TextData`, `text` (which isn't a property on Strings) should be undefined.

If you remove the destructuring and then refer to `TextData` directly, it should work.

Comment: Thank you SeanMcP, accepted and upvoted. Got another issue, are you familiar with this problem >>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313537/while-adding-a-twitter-component-getting-error-and-site-not-loading

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons why you might have this issue:

1. There is no a `TextData` variable in the scope of the `middleSection.js` file
2. `TextData` is exported as a string from `textData1.js`, hence it can't be destructured

Replace the following line

```js
text.substring(0, 50)
```

by

```js
data1.substring(0, 50)
```

And remove the line

```js
const { text } = TextData;
```