# Default value is not displaying in select drop down box of react hooks app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react hooks select drop down, the default value is not displaying. On page load I would like to display `Select Position` in the drop down.
Could someone please advise why it is not displaying the default value ?

code sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-diffie-kx9h49?file=/src/App.js:0-991

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState("Select Position");
  const [positionType, setPositionType] = useState([
    "Goal Keeper",
    "Striker",
    "Attacking Midfielder",
    "Right Midfielder",
    "Defending Midfielder",
    "Left Midfielder",
    "Center Back",
    "Right Fullback",
    "Left Fullback"
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultValue(defaultValue);
  }, []);

  const handlePositionTypeChange = (e) =>
    console.log(positionType[e.target.value]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Position</label>
      <select
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
        onChange={(e) => handlePositionTypeChange(e)}
        key={defaultValue}
        className="browser-default custom-select"
      >
        {positionType.map((position, key) => (
          <option value={key}>{position}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: option value should be assigned a position instead of key as key is giving index only.You can check my below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("Select Position");
  const [positionType, setPositionType] = useState([
    "Goal Keeper",
    "Striker",
    "Attacking Midfielder",
    "Right Midfielder",
    "Defending Midfielder",
    "Left Midfielder",
    "Center Back",
    "Right Fullback",
    "Left Fullback"
  ]);


  const handlePositionTypeChange = (e) => {
    console.log("e.target.value", e.target.value);
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label>Position</label>

      <select
        value={selectedValue ? selectedValue : ""}
        onChange={handlePositionTypeChange}
        className="browser-default custom-select"
      >
        <option value="Select Position" disabled>
          Select a color...
        </option>
        {positionType?.map((position, key) => (
          <option key={key} value={position}>
            {position}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-sunset-xkl1zz?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: In this approach we need to have two ``option`` tags in react component right ?

Comment: If you want to keep it in array then one option is ok otherwise you can take two option tag separately.

Comment: @Shubam Sharma ..Sorry just looked again, after implemented the default value, the selected value from drop down is not displaying.

Comment: It always show the default ``Select a position`` even after selecting any value from drop down

Comment: @soccerway Inside the handlePostionTypeChange you have to set the state using event.target.value ,then you can use it further in you code.I have update the answer `setSelectedValue(e.target.value);`.Please check

Comment: Thank you, its all good now.  Have you come across implementing twitter feeds in react hooks, could you please advise what is the problem here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72313537/while-adding-a-twitter-component-getting-error-and-site-not-loading